# iOS push notification and certificate issues

Tags: ios, push

I have a pretty basic push notification question I was hoping someone could quickly answer for me:

I am developing an application for another person and everything is completed except for push notification integration. The other person logged into his developer account, created an App ID (lets say com.company.myApp), configured it for push notification and created a development and production SSL Push certificate.

Up to this point, I have been using MY personal developer account, and my question is 2 fold:

1) If I create an App ID that matches the one my customer made (com.company.myApp) and test it in development, will the push notification trigger in my app? I am guessing not since I assume there must be some tie to the other persons account within these certificates.

2) In general, is it possible to develop an application with a developer license A, and have it submit to iTunes Connect belonging to the owner of license B?

In essence, I am trying to figure out if I need to obtain this other persons developer license certificates in order to fully create an app for them or if I can develop on my certificates and simply log into their iTunes Connect and upload the app even though the app was code signed by my certificate. Developing applications for other people is a new realm for me and so how all these licenses/certificates come into effect is a tad confusing.

I hope this scenario makes sense, if not I can try to further clarify.

Comment: What type of flatform you use for server-side?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of certificates:

1. **Developer:** 
   You can you use it to 2 everything you mentioned in `1)`
   and `2)` as long as you add it to your key chain.
2. **Distribution:** 
   When submitting the app this is the certificate you
   need to have in order to upload

Answer (score -1):

your basic push notification solution is

1.your **.cer** certification  use another app **.cer** certification ....thats why your certification dont match       [enter link description here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Comment: Could you include relevant information of the link in the body of the post?